# Where the mongodb sharded collection index info stored?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

Let's suppose that a sharded collection with shard key named "skey"
and there is another indexed but not shard key named "ikey"

if the query like this,

```
db.collection.find({"ikey": "something"})
```

It will search the docs across the all shards because it is not a shard key.

At this point, how does the mongos know it should be searched across the shards? where is that index information stored? configServer? or each sharded mongod server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices are stored on the individual shard. This goes for both the shard key and all other indices.

The `mongos` holds a cache of so called key ranges of the shard key for each shard. The key ranges are stored at the config servers which will be contacted by the `mongos` instances on certain occasions to retrieve those key ranges and their associated shards. The key ranges are basically a dictionary of shard key values and the *name* of the shard on which the document with the respective shard key lives on.

So if you query by shard key, `mongos` can identify the shards which hold the data and sends the query to the shards which hold the data with the defined key range(s). The shards then return the data to the `mongos`, which will sort the returned data, if necessary.

Mongos knows it has to send the query to all shards simply because the query does not contain the shard key for the respective collection.

Comment: thanks, could you give me some document links related this question?

Comment: I've got a detail question after reading your answer. let's think about count, if the count indexed, and 1,3 value stored at shard1 and 2,4 value stored at shard2. It could be happened if the count key is not a shard key. then, what ranges stored each shard?

Comment: 1 and 3 on shard1, 2 and 4 on shard 2. for Details, please see [the docs concerning Sharded Cluster Query Routing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/)